# Array is not being populated/assigned in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

```
shopt -s nullglob
array=(~/unsorted_files/*.jpg)

for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++)); do

echo "${array[$i]}"

done
```

Enclosed is the code I am trying to utilise in order to parse jpg files from a directory, and then print them. Running the code through shell check, I am advised that although the array has been referenced it has not been assigned.

I am confused by this. My understanding is that = is the assignment operator, and as such then, I assumed (wrongly it appears) that I am assigning all files with are of the jpg file type, to the array.

Comment: The code you show only assigns to `array` and not to `arr`.  Perhaps `${#arr[@]}` is a typo and shellcheck has caught it for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the for loop counter check. You have populated `array` but checking `arr` in loop. Fix it as below

```
for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++)); do
```

Because of the false expression evaluation, the body of the loop is never entered even though the array is *likely* populated by your jpeg files.